# How to color/remove the separator between last and second to last row in a SwiftUI List?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm using simple SwiftUI Lists such as

```
List {
  Text("A")
  Text("A")
  Text("A")
}
```

I've already managed to remove the standard dividers by adding `UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear`, however there seems to be another slim light gray divider between the last and second to last element:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I remove this divider or change its color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ScrollView` with `ForEach` instead of default `List`. It will be without default styling, and you can define your own style.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var words = (1...50).map{ String($0) }
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(self.words, id: \.self) { word in
                    Text(word)
                }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've already managed to remove the standard dividers by adding
>   UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear

Use instead

```
UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
```

Comment: This only removes the standard list separator, not that other grey line pictured in the screenshot.

Comment: @fasoh, with the provided List code I don't see any *additional* line, and actually it does not result in screenshot, so would you provide all your code.